# Laravel route model binding matches even though I'm using the incorrect ulid

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

This is pretty strange...

I've started using ulids on my models I'm getting model matches when I should be receiving a 404

```
Route::get('{club}/{membership}/signup', function (Club $club, Membership $membership) {
    dd($club, $membership);
})->name('signup.create');
```

You can see in my picture that first model I'm dumping should have a ulid ending in mx9, not szf. I have another model using zsf, but this is not the model I'm attempting to retrieve.

You can see the second ulid in the url is a membership object id, and this is also returning a model even though I'm only passing `01gz` (the first 4 characters)

[image]

Anyone else using ulids?

PS
I'm using PHP 8.1 and Laravel 10

Answer (score 1):

Ok ok.

So here is what was going on for me...

I decided to keep my id as the typical auto incrementing id and added a separate ulid column. I was using the HasUlid trait on my model, but Laravel was still using id and the start of that ulid was `01` which was resolving to the id of 1.

I'm now calling `getRouteKeyName` and returning `ulid` and it's now working!

What a roller coaster of emotion! lol